# Piped FFMPEG won't write frames correctly

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pipe

I am using Python's Image module to load JPEGs and modify them. After I have a modified image, I want to load that image in to a video, using more modified images as frames in my video.

I have 3 programs written to do this:
ImEdit (My image editing module that I wrote)
VideoWriter (writes to an mp4 file using FFMPEG) and
VideoMaker (The file I'm using to do everything)

My VideoWriter looks like this...

```
import subprocess as sp
import os
import Image
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"

class VideoWriter():
   def __init__(self,xsize=480,ysize=360,FPS=29,
            outDir=None,outFile=None):

   if outDir is None:
      print("No specified output directory. Using default.")
      outDir = "./VideoOut"
   if outFile is None:
      print("No specified output file. Setting temporary.")
      outFile = "temp.mp4"
   if (outDir and outFile) is True:
      if os.path.exists(outDir+outFile):
         print("File path",outDir+outFile, "already exists:",
               "change output filename or",
               "overwriting will occur.")
   self.outDir = outDir
   self.outFile = outFile
   self.xsize,self.ysize,self.FPS = xsize,ysize,FPS

   self.buildWriter()

def setOutFile(self,fileName):
   self.outFile = filename

def setOutDir(self,dirName):
   self.outDir = dirName

def buildWriter(self):
   commandWriter = [FFMPEG_BIN,
                    '-y',
                    '-f', 'rawvideo',
                    '-vcodec','mjpeg',
                    '-s', '480x360',#.format(480,
                    '-i', '-',
                    '-an', #No audio
                    '-r', str(29),
                    './{}//{}'.format(self.outDir,self.outFile)]
   self.pW = sp.Popen(commandWriter,
                      stdin = sp.PIPE)

def writeFrame(self,ImEditObj):
   stringData = ImEditObj.getIm().tostring()
   im = Image.fromstring("RGB",(309,424),stringData)
   im.save(self.pW.stdin, "JPEG")
   self.pW.stdin.flush()

def finish(self):
   self.pW.communicate()
   self.pW.stdin.close()
```

ImEditObj.getIm() returns an instance of a Python Image object

This code works to the extent that I can load one frame in to the video and no matter how many more calls to writeFrame that I do, the video only every ends up being one frame long. I have other code that works as far as making a video out of single frames and that code is nearly identical to this code. I don't know what difference there is though that makes this code not work as intended where the other code does work.

My question is...
How can I modify my VideoWriter class so that I can pass in an instance of an Python's Image object and write that frame to an output file? I also would like to be able to write more than one frame to the video.

I've spent 5 hours or more trying to debug this, having not found anything helpful on the internet, so if I missed any StackOverflow questions that would point me in the right direction, those would be appreciated...

EDIT:
After a bit more debugging, the issue may have been that I was trying to write to a file that already existed, however, this doesn't make much sense with the -y flag in my commandWriter. the -y flag should overwrite any file that already exists. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you follow the OpenCV [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) in writing videos. This is a very common way of writing video files from Python, so you should find many answers on the internet, if you can't get certain things to work.

Note that the VideoWriter will discard (and won't write) any frames that are not in the exact same pixel size that you give it on initialization.

Comment: I have tried SO MUCH to use OpenCV and I've never gotten it to work. I don't know why it won't work, but it just doesn't. I'll check out the communicate method. I don't know if it will work for me since it closes the file, but I haven't gone extensively through the other question you provided.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, so my answer is plain wrong. Sorry! I'll remove it tomorrow. Maybe you should try to get OpenCV working after all. It's normally just a package install away. Even if you are on Windows, when following the documentation (copying the pre-built python files into the right directory) you should get it to work.

Comment: Have you checked stdout and stderr from the ffmpeg process to give you a clue to what might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps OpenCV might work, but the problem I have with that is that I can't read videos at all. The frameCap always returns false so my video never opens. Haven't tried writing any videos with OpenCV 'cause I couldn't even open anything.

As far as another problem I'm having with my code, writing the same frame to the output file won't work. If I process an image that returns image1, then write it, then process the same image with another input parameter that ends up returning the exact same pixels that image1 has, the second write to my video isn't completed...

Comment: In terms of beginning to end, what would I have to do to get rid of OpenCV and start completely over with it? At this point, I would totally be OK with trying it out again with how frustrated I am with ffmpeg.